# Programmatically play blackberry default ringtone in all version

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to play blackberry default ringtones. If yes how? and what will be the code. please help if anyone have any idea.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

"You cannot directly access and play the RIM tones - they are content-protected.

What you *can* do is set up your own alert profile that is added to the BB Profiles. This profile can access the on-board ringtones. You fire this profile using NotificationManager.

See the NotificationsDemo that ships wiht the JDE."

Source: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Ring-Tones/m-p/343755#M63152